# Some elements are not seen in the nested recyclerview after doing smooth scroll to position 0

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, scrollto

I have a recyclerview inside another recycler view, but when I apply the method to the parent to go to a certain child, some recyclerview of those children are not seen, but the rest of the child is seen. The internal recyclerview is as follows.

```
                val layout = GridLayoutManager(itemView.context, 2)
                layout.recycleChildrenOnDetach = true
                layoutManager = layout

                val mAdapter = Adapter(onChildItemClick)

                adapter = mAdapter
                mAdapter.oldList = datesModelObject.list

                isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
                setHasFixedSize(true)

                
             setRecycledViewPool(RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed

```
layout.recycleChildrenOnDetach = true
```

and work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

From official [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setRecycledViewPool(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool)):

> Recycled view pools allow multiple **RecyclerView**s to share a common pool of scrap views. This can be useful if you have multiple **RecyclerView**s with adapters that use the same view types, for example if you have several data sets with the same kinds of item views displayed by a **ViewPager**.

By default, 5 `ViewHolder`s are retained in the pool for a particular **viewType**. If you want to change that count, it may be done this way:

```
recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool()
            .setMaxRecycledViews(SOME_VIEW_TYPE, POOL_CAPACITY);
```